# Excel sharepoint scalability

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint, scalability

We have a huge set of linked (15+ files) and huge .xlsx and .xlsm spreadsheets (2-17 Mb) on a network drive, and they've grown to a point where it fails in various ways on a daily basis (Office 2010).

Now, we're doing things right in a few months with a new system, but could an interim Sharepoint investment fix or improve some of the stability issues in the short term ?

Comment: did you know about transfer all the documents (for example more that 100 files) into another document library, can help from windows explorer?

Comment: Just copy the files to another folder ? No i didn't will it ?

Comment: for transfer many folder and files like copy and paste in windows. by click "on open with windows explorer" and just copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i want to manage it ,

1. use DFS to fix the FQDN of my file address that want to link together
2. set versioning of my SharePoint library on
3. update my softwares and server
4. copy with the synchronize softwares or backup solutions
5. create a map network drive on static letter Drive with GPO with Active directory Group Policy